# Can't logout mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, logout

I have created a login/logout system in my application but it's not working even using `session_start();`, `session_destroy();` and `session_unset ();` etc.

Here is what I have done so far:

the first page (login)

```
<?php
    if(
    !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])||
    !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])||
    ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])!="admin"||
    ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!="admin")
     )
{
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Accès refusé"');
echo 'Accès refusé';
exit;
}
else
session_start (); 
$_SESSION['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = "admin"; 
$_SESSION['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = "admin"; 
echo '
```

and this is the logout part

```
<?php

session_start();
session_unset ();
session_destroy(); 
header("Location: index.php");
die;    
?>
```

The problem is that the session is not destroyed, even when clicking the logout button.

Comment: That should be `if{` not `if(`, followed by `}` and not `)` etc. Plus you need `session_start();` in every page.

Comment: I have session_start() in every page + it's if(condition) {} this is how i work all the time

Comment: Your **"style"** is very confusing, even if it does work for you.

Comment: Yes I saw that, however, `session_start();`, is usually at the **top** of the page, not tucked down below in an `else`. Probably why it's getting destroyed.

Comment: it's after the (else) because in my case or to put it right the condition i begin with is if there is not login or password or if they are wrong in this case nothing must happens but in the other case a session should start and a member page shows out (after the echo)

Comment: @Fred - his if contains functional syntax, just looks odd the way it is displayed here.

Comment: @KaiQing **Odd** indeed. Oh well, I guess it's kind of like being a pharmacist, and having to read a new doctor's handwriting ;-)

Comment: It's the standard login of PHP, not odd at all !!

Comment: @user2507171 I said "odd", and not "bad" ;-)

Comment: @user2507171 Is there anything else below `echo '` in your first body of posted code? May be irrelevant, just on a *need-to-know basis*

Comment: below echo there is the code of the page (member) all in html

Comment: @user2507171 Ok, so it's not part of the problem then. Ok... *back to the 'ol drawing board*.

Comment: @user2507171 Have you tried `exit;` instead of `die;` or even removing it altogether?

Comment: Yes I did, nothing changed

Comment: I guess that what shoud I do is to unset PHP_AUTH_USER variables but how I don't know, I have tried this
PHP_AUTH_USER=null;
PHP_AUTH_USER="";
but still same issue

Comment: *baffled*. Maybe something to do with your `.htaccess` and/or `php.ini`?

Comment: Taken from the PHP manual: "If you want to change the session id on each log in, make sure to use `session_regenerate_id(true)` during the log in process." Not sure if it will be of use.

Comment: @Fred I don't know, what should I do ?

Comment: Found this: "`$_SESSION = array();` after calling `session_destroy();`"

Comment: @user2507171 Those infos above were found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9971669/1415724 - might be some info in there you can use.

Comment: @user2507171 Btw, did you say that you tried putting `session_start();` "also" at the **top** of the login page, while keeping the other one intact and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and I kept it at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using http authentication
- Cookies and Sessions does not have any influence on http authentication
- ["No correct way exists" to logout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449914/1503018).

Create another login/logout system, it's not hard.

Comment: Is it going to change anything if I use another browser ?

Comment: @user2507171, yes, You will be able to handle auth with cookies and sessions.

Comment: Might change it if you use another browser sure, but it still doesn't fix the "existing" issue at hand. What if someone uses the same you're using now?

Comment: @user2507171 Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12866277/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3490680/1415724

Comment: I didn't even notice that.